# How to resolve external window, form and sliced imaging errors regarding Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a table full of sliced images that are supposed to be composed together to create a full image, and a product order form on single page.

The confirmation box, form calculation, and open/close window (linking to an external page) functions are not working despite sourcing the code from reliable resources.

The table of sliced images is not displaying either, despite my teacher insisting javascript can create the image independently without having to code a table in HTML.

Can someone help point out my sources of errors and explain why they are happening?

---

#### Example

```js
//FORM CALCULATION BUTTON
function multiplyBy() {
  "use strict";
  var num1;
  var num2;
  num1 = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("price").value;
  document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}
// FORM CONFIRM BOX
function Submit() {
  "use strict";
  var number;
  var r = Submit("Item Discription: Red Bowl\nQuantity: 1\nPrice: 
                 $225 .00\ nTotal Price: $300 .00\ nPress the OK button to confirm!");
                 if (r === true) {
    number = "Your order has been confirmed";
  } else {
    number = "Your order has been cleared";
  }
  document.getElementById("orderForm").innerHTML = number;
}
//FOOTER- OPEN AND CLOSE FORM WINDOW
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
  "use strict";
  myWindow =
    window.open("members_order.html", "_blank",
                "width=980, height=1000");
}

function closeWin() {
  "use strict";
  myWindow.close();
}
//SLICED IMAGES
var numRows = 4;
var numCols = 5;
var showTable = "";
for (var j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
  showTable += "<tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    showTable += "<td><img src='images/bcpot002_r";
    showTable += (j + 1);
    showTable += "_c";
    showTable += (i + 1);
    showTable += ".jpg'/></td>";
  }
  showTable += "</tr>";
}
document.writeln(showTable);
```

```html
<script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
<!--FORM-->
<form id="orderForm" action="members_order.html" onsubmit="return submit()" method="get">
   <tr>
      <th>Item Discription:</th>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="discription" name="discription" value="Red Bowl" size="30"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Quantity:</th>
      <td><input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"></td>
      <th>Price:</th>
      <td><input type="number" id="price" name="price" value="225.00"></td>
      <td><input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" value="Calculate Total" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Total Price:</th>
      <td><input type="number" id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice" value="225.00"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="reset" onClick="reset()" value="Clear" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" onClick="Submit()" value="Submit" /></td>
   </tr>
</form>
</table>
<!--WINDOW BUTTONS-->
<button type="button" onClick="closeWin()">Close Order Page</button>
<button onclick="openWin()"></button>
```

Comment: Please scale this down to one question at a time. Also *"not working"* is fairly meaningless without defining expectations and errors. Just running the code shown throws an error as seen in the snippet console